# how to convert a column to an array in presto

Tags: sql, arrays, aggregate-functions, presto

Postgres provides a way to turn a column into an array. Samle query:

```sql
WITH
    dataset AS (
        SELECT '1' as a
        union
        SELECT '2' as a
        union
        SELECT '3' as a
    )
SELECT
    array(select a from dataset) as array_result;
```

returns

```
| array_result |
|--------------|
| {2,3,1}      |
```

How to do the same with Presto SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_agg(x [ORDER BY y])](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html)  aggregation function:

```
WITH
    dataset AS (
        SELECT '1' as a
        union all
        SELECT '2' as a
        union all
        SELECT '3' as a
    )
SELECT
    array_agg(a) as array_result from dataset;
```

Result:

```
['3', '2', '1']
```

If you need `array<int>`, cast before aggregation:  `array_agg(cast(a as int))`